# Finding if data in array is periodic

Tags: fft

I have a very large array (about 500.000 in size). I've plotted the array in chunks and founded at the tail of the array there is a periodic behavior, so I want to know if there is a way to know if it is periodic an if so what is its period?

I don't have any idea about signal processing so I need to know if there is a simple and straight forward method to check it. I'm using Python and Mathlab.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try pwelch in Matlab.  You should try to bound the range of periods you think might be present in your array because you want a DFT size that contains enough cycles and a rule-of thumb should be around 10 periods.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically, what you probably want is the *autocorrelation* function. That function is a function on a function over time or a sequence, which gives you info about how similar your signal is to itself when shifted by shift $\tau$.

If your signal is periodic with period $\tau$, then it will be very similar to itself when shifted by $\tau$, $2\tau$, $3\tau$, and so on. So, you'll get $\tau$-periodic peaks in your autocorrelation function

A very common thing to do is to look at the *Power Spectral Density* (PSD), which is, in fact, the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function. You can, however, in your sampled case, calculate the PSD directly by Fourier-transforming (Matlab function `fft`) your sequence and finding the `abs²` of it. The peaks correspond to periodicities.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thank you for your answer. Do you know any website in where I can find more info and examples about it?

Comment: This one. You really don't  need more examples. You need how to use Matlab, and you need how to use the fft function (which is really just `fft(data)`), and you need to be able to plot things.